# how to get voice wake-up on Android

Tags: speech-recognition, voice, phrase

I want to wake-up some function in the Android APP by saying "hello, Jack". As far as I know, there is a technology named "phrase spotting" to recognise a certain speech, e.g. "hello, Jack". but I have no idea to implement the "phrase spotting".

Anyone has more ideas or suggestions ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest and resource-efficient way would be to implement dynamic time warping DTW for keyword spotting

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping

http://www.purduecal.edu/ece/WSEAS.pdf

You can use CMUSphinx toolkit to extract MFCC features, that will save a lot of time implementing them

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net

Answer (score -1):

I suggest this simple approach first.

Start with using a simple Set to match the keywords you you want as in the class below:

```
public class WordMatcher
{
    private Set<String> words;
    public static final int NOT_IN = -1;

    public WordMatcher(String... wordsIn)
    {
        this(Arrays.asList(wordsIn));
    }

    public WordMatcher(List<String> wordsIn)
    {
        //care about order so we can execute isInAt
        words = new LinkedHashSet<String>(wordsIn);
    }

    public Set<String> getWords()
    {
        return words;
    }

    public boolean isIn(String word)
    {
        return words.contains(word);
    }

    public boolean isIn(String [] wordsIn)
    {
        boolean wordIn = false;
        for (String word : wordsIn)
        {
            if (isIn(word))
            {
                wordIn = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return wordIn;
    }
```

Process the recognition results like this:

```
@Override
protected void
        onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    WordMatcher matchHello = new WordMatcher("hello");
    WordMatcher matchJack = new WordMatcher("jack");

    if (requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE)
    {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            List<String> heard =
                    data.
                    getStringArrayListExtra
                            (RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

            for (String oneResult : heard)
            {
                if (matchHello.isIn(oneResult.split(" ")) && matchJack.isIn(oneResult.split(" "))
                {
                     //SUCCESS!! do something here
                }


            }
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "error code: " + resultCode);
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Second, if that fails introduce "sounds like" matching algorithms such as [Soundex](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/language/Soundex.html).

Also, you may want to investigate using the SpeechRecognizer class directly to run speech recognition in the background, rather than using the RecognizerIntent which produces a dialog.